# i am trying to create order but no such sku on stripe api

Tags: stripe-payments

i am trying to create order but no such sku on stripe api. is it possible to create order on stripe without creating a product? i just want to store the order on stripe.

```
const orderRes = await stripe.orders.create({
    currency: 'usd',
    email: 'iamaemail@gmail.com',
    items: [
      {type: 'sku', parent: 'sku_7hAchfCjchvSHL'},
    ],
    shipping: {
      name: 'Jenny Rosen',
      address: {
        line1: '1234 Main Street',
        city: 'San Francisco',
        state: 'CA',
        country: 'US',
        postal_code: '94111',
      },
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/orders), the Orders API has been deprecated and is not SCA compliant (which affects if charges made via this API will succeed for European merchants or end-users).

If you look at the [Stripe API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/orders/create) for creating an Order object, you can see that only the `currency` parameter is required. If you are going to specify a value for the `parent` parameter for an element in the `items` hash, you must ensure that you are using a SKU object that was created in Test Mode or Live Mode (whichever matches the environment in which you're trying to create the Order object), and that the SKU is correct. This SKU id appears to not match any SKU id in your Stripe account (which is why you're getting the error that you mention).

Comment: so i need to create a product in stripe in order to create an order?